# Add new path to current URL in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

having this example where 'Route' name could be any name

```
 <Route path='/Page/:Route/'>
  <Page1/>
</Route>
<Route path='/Page/:Route/:subRoute'>
  <Page1/>
</Route>
```

if I am currently in **/Page/:Route**, how can I append to the current URL the **subRoute**
Every time I use history.push like this

```
history.push(`${history.location.pathname`}/${item.name})
```

my URL ends like this

http://localhost:3001/Page/Route/SubRoute/Route/SubRoute/Route/SubRoute

what I want is just to change the URL from a dropwdown select, i am not actually navigating to a different page, I just want to add the item name that I select from the drowpdown menu.

Expected result

DrowpDownMenu Items:

1. SubRoute1
2. SubRoute2
3. SubRoute3

> ```
> http://localhost:3001/Page/Route/SubRoute1
> http://localhost:3001/Page/Route/SubRoute2
> http://localhost:3001/Page/Route/SubRoute3
> ```

Comment: Is `"/Page/Route/SubRoute/Route/SubRoute/Route/SubRoute"` the desired result, or the unexpected result? Can you clarify what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom` v5 you can build nested links and routes using the [`useRouteMatch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) hook to build from the currently matched `Route`'s `path` and `url`. `useRouteMatch` returns a `match` object.

> [match](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/match)
>
> A match object contains information about how a `<Route path>` matched
> the URL. match objects contain the following properties:
>
> - params - (object) Key/value pairs parsed from the URL corresponding to the dynamic segments of the path
> - isExact - (boolean) true if the entire URL was matched (no trailing characters)
> - path - (string) The path pattern used to match. Useful for building nested `<Route>`s
> - **url - (string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful for building nested `<Link>`s**

In `Page1` component use the `useRouteMatch` hook to build a link from the current path.

Example:

```
const { url } = useRouteMatch();

...

history.replace(`${url}/${item.name}`);
```

You can actually combine your routes into a single `Route` with an array of `path` values to match and render.

```
<Route path={['/Page/:route/:subRoute', '/Page/:route']}>
  <Page1/>
</Route>
```

If you need to "listen" for changes to the route path changing then use the [`useParams`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) and `useEffect` hooks to issue any side-effects.

Example:

```
const { route, subRoute } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  if (subRoute) {
    // handle sub-route value change
  }
}, [subRoute]);
```